# Authentication with Spring OAuth2 vs Principal in SpringSession

Tags: java, spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, microservices

I'm building new Java application using microservices architecture and have to deal with user authentication across separate services. I see two main approaches to this problem:

**1) Spring OAuth2 + Spring cloud security** which uses Oauth token in Authorization header with each request. Token is generated/validated by separate authentication service. In each request I then able to get authentication principal with user identity and assigned roles, to make a call to other service I simply use Oauth2RestTemplate which propagates authorization header automatically.

**2) Spring Session + Spring security** with authentication kept in session which is in turn stored in Redis (or somewhere else) and keyed by session id. In this case instead of Authorization header client will have session cookie, each microservice will have access to this session and authentication principal.
There's no ready-made restTemplate to propagate session cookie though, but it's a matter of few lines of code, and not a deciding factor here.

Both solutions work fine, so what's the benefits of OAuth2 if having session (pulling it from Redis each time) is enough?

It seems that OAuth2 approach may be preferable when building language independent solution whereas Spring session will work only with Java microservices.

Could someone please explain other benefits of token-based authentication?

Comment: It does not require state so it's more scalable.

Comment: When microservice gets request with Authorization header it pulls authentication info (user identity, roles etc) from Authentication server, same with session - microservice gets request with session cookie and pulls session object from Redis. Looks very similar.

Comment: *It depends on your specifics* but the token could contain all this information as embedded metadata.